# Artificial time implementation in clojure

Tags: timer, clojure

I know that it's usually a good idea to keep away from state when programming clojure. However, time seems to me something very stateful.

My goal is to represent time in my game I am writing in clojure. My idea was to run a timer as a seperate process and read its value whenever needed but there doesn't seem to be any natural way of acheiving this in clojure.

How would you implement time in a simple roleplaying game in clojure?

Comment: I don't think you need to keep a state in this situation. Just get the time when you start, then it is just a matter of substracting the current time.

Comment: "time when you start" is a form of state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adapted the code from [this Java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650881/1876583) into my date-dif function:

```
(defn date-dif [d1 d2]
  (let [tu java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit/SECONDS
        t1 (. d1 getTime)
        t2 (. d2 getTime)]
    (. tu convert (- t2 t1) java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit/MILLISECONDS)))

(defn start-timer []
  (let [cur-time (new java.util.Date)]
    (fn [] (date-dif cur-time (new java.util.Date)))))
```

`start-timer` will create and return a function that, when called, returns the number of seconds since the function was created. To use it, do something like this:

```
rpg-time.core> (def my-timer (start-timer))
#'rpg-time.core/my-timer
rpg-time.core> (my-timer)
3
rpg-time.core> (my-timer)
5
rpg-time.core> (my-timer)
6
```

If you want a different unit of time, instead of seconds, replace SECONDS with something more appropriate from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html).

There are certainly other options you can consider. This is just the first one I thought of, and it isn't very hard to code or use.

Answer (score 2):

Timer is pretty stateless. Actually timer is a point in time in which it started.

I will use [`clj-time`](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) here for simplicity.

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as t]
         '[clj-time.coerce :as c])

(defn timer
  []
  (let [now-sec #(-> (t/now) c/to-long (/ 1000) int)
        start (now-sec)]
    #(- (now-sec) start)))

(def my-timer (timer))
;; after a second
(my-timer)
;;=> 1
;; and after 2 seconds more
(my-timer)
;;=> 3
```

Comment: How can you say that a timer is stateless when it needs to remember the time in which it started?

Comment: @WolfeFan it is stateless in terms that it has no any mutable state, but maybe it is not proper usage of this word.

Comment: this is wrong, `timer` function is touching global state on `t/now`